# Expansion of functions in the real domain

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

When I try

```
FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[x^(1/12)(1/12) LerchPhi[x,1,1/12]]]
```

I have a nice answer with many complex numbers.

Is there any way to have the expression with just real terms ? As an example, changing (1/12) by (1/4) leads to beautiful results.the argument "x" is real and (value between 0 and 1).

Thanks for your help

Comment: So is the question about for which values of the parameters your function is real valued for real x ?

Comment: @Nasser ; the result is a real number. I gave the case of (1/4) because of its beauty.

Comment: The result of your expression is complex, **not real**, if $x>1$.

Comment: @Jens He does state that the `x` has a value in the interval (0, 1).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh yes, I missed that. Anyway, *Mathematica* can't be expected to know that...

Answer (score 2):

A combination of `ComplexExpand` and `FullSimplify` can get you an expression without any complex terms:

```
FullSimplify[
 ComplexExpand[
  FunctionExpand[x^(1/12) (1/12) LerchPhi[x, 1, 1/12]],
  TargetFunctions -> {Re}],
 0 < x < 1]

(* 1/24 (-2 Sqrt[3] ArcCot[(1 - 2/x^(1/12))/Sqrt[3]] - 
   2 ArcCot[Sqrt[3] - 2/x^(1/12)] + 
   2 Sqrt[3] ArcCot[(1 + 2/x^(1/12))/Sqrt[3]] + 
   2 ArcCot[Sqrt[3] + 2/x^(1/12)] + 
   2 Sqrt[3] ArcCoth[(1 + x^(1/6))/(Sqrt[3] x^(1/12))] + 
   4 ArcTan[x^(1/12)] + 
   Log[3/(-1 + x^(1/12))^2 - 2/(1 - x^(1/12) + x^(1/6))] + 
   2 Log[1 + x^(1/12)])  *)
```

Comment: @Simon : as you understood, Iam not a cleaver user of MMa. The result you sent me is a perfect illustration of my problems (in a general manner). How can I simplify such above expression using the rules such as ArcTan[a]+ArcTan[b]=..., Log[a]+Log[b]=... ?
Thanks for helping the old dinosaure !

Comment: @Simon: how could I define rules in order that the result be just a linear combination of ArcTan's and ArcTanh's ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, for fine control over the form of the expression I think you will have to supply explicit transformation rules, e.g. `% /. {ArcCot[a_] :> ArcTan[1/a], ArcCoth[a_] :> ArcTanh[1/a], Log[a_] :> 2 ArcTanh[(-1 + a)/(1 + a)]}`

Comment: @SimonWoods, I am sorry for my ignorance. Where do I write what you say ? Currently, I work what you sent me by hand and it is a nightmare ! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, enter it into a new cell below the output of the FullSimplify.