# How to express an expression with only ArcTan and ArcTanh?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I have an expression which is simply

```
(j/k) x^(j/k) LerchPhi[x,1,j/k)]
```

where `0 < j < k`.

Manually I have been able (tedious work) to obtain only `ArcTan`'s and `ArcTanh`'s. How could I ask *Mathematica* to do this automatically in the most compact form ?

Comment: Clarify your question. What exactly do you intend to do with that expression? `Simplify` or what?

Comment: @RunnyKine, I think the OP is looking for a generalisation of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29755/862).

Comment: @SimonWoods. Ah I see.

Comment: @RunnyKine. It is a kind of simplification. I have been able to do this by hand and arrived to quite nice linear combinations of ArcTan's and ArcTanh's. What I would like to learn is how to formulate the problem and get the most compact form of the result (ideally, one ArcTan and one ArcTanh, but linear combinations will be good). I am not very good (this is an understatement).

Answer (score 9):

This should get you started. For some reason *Mathematica* returns `LerchPhi[x, 1, j/k]` unevaluated if the third argument is a symbol. So let's assume $j = 1$ and $k = 4$ (it does meet your requirement $0 < j < k$ ).

Let's first define some complexity function:

```
cf[k_][e_] :=  k Count[e, _Log | _ArcCot | _ArcCoth, Infinity] + LeafCount[e]
```

Now we simplify:

```
FullSimplify[ FunctionExpand[(1/4) x^(1/4) LerchPhi[x, 1, 1/4]], 
              ComplexityFunction -> cf[#]] & /@ Range[4]
```

> ```
> {1/2 (ArcTan[x^(1/4)] + ArcTanh[x^(1/4)]), 1/2 (ArcTan[x^(1/4)] + ArcTanh[x^(1/4)]),
>  1/2 (ArcTan[x^(1/4)] + ArcTanh[x^(1/4)]),   1/2 (ArcTan[x^(1/4)] + ArcTanh[x^(1/4)])}
> ```

Looks like it converged fast to a nicely simplified expression in terms of only `ArcTan` and `ArcTanh`

> ```
> 1/2 (ArcTan[x^(1/4)] + ArcTanh[x^(1/4)])
> ```

Admittedly, for this lone case, `FunctionExpand` will do just fine, but if you're trying to generalize this, you'll need to use the `ComplexityFunction`. To see this try:

```
FunctionExpand[(1/8) x^(1/8) LerchPhi[x, 1, 1/8]]
```

You'll get your answer in terms of `Log` only

> ```
> x^(1/8) ( -(Log[1 - x^(1/8)]/(8 x^(1/8))) 
>           + (I Log[1 - I x^(1/8)])/(8 x^(1/8)) 
>           - (I Log[1 + I x^(1/8)])/(8 x^(1/8)) 
>           + Log[1 + x^(1/8)]/(8 x^(1/8)) 
>           - ((-1)^(1/4) Log[1 - E^(-((I π)/4)) x^(1/8)])/(8 x^(1/8)) 
>           + ((-1)^(3/4) Log[1 - E^((I π)/4) x^(1/8)])/(8 x^(1/8)) 
>           - ((-1)^(3/4) Log[1 - E^(-((3 I π)/4)) x^(1/8)])/(8 x^(1/8)) 
>           + ((-1)^(1/4) Log[1 - E^((3 I π)/4) x^(1/8)])/(8 x^(1/8)))
> ```

But if we apply our `cf`:

```
FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[(1/8) x^(1/8) LerchPhi[x, 1, 1/8]], ComplexityFunction -> cf[1]]
```

We obtain:

```
1/4 (ArcTan[x^(1/8)] + ArcTanh[x^(1/8)] - (-1)^( 3/4) (ArcTan[(-1)^(1/4) x^(1/8)] 
+ ArcTanh[(-1)^(1/4) x^(1/8)]))
```

Again, in terms of only `ArcTan` and `ArcTanh`.

Comment: This looks as magics ! It is almost what I am looking for.If I may ask : is it feasible to remove the roots of (-1) and use automatically the multiple angles formulas for ArcTan and ArcTanh ? This is what I made by hand.  Thanks for you help to the old idiot.

Comment: It does not seem to like (1/3)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Hmmm, interesting. I wonder why. Looking into it.

Comment: I do not know how to post a Word document to show you my formulas (if you are interested). In any manner, many thanks for your help from the old idiot !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. I'm glad I could help. If you have a cloud storage you could upload it there and put a link to it here.

Comment: I even don't know what is a cloud storage (joke, but I don't know how to make one). I told you I am old and idiot ! Thanks again.

Comment: @RunnyKine I admire your solution. Could you kindly comment on what is the idea behind this: k Count[e, _Log | _ArcCot | _ArcCoth, Infinity] part of the complexity function? I mean that the ComplexityFunction->LeafCount works as well both with 1/4 and 1/8 and does not work at 1/3 as well. But this is not my point. I would like to understand better, how to construct the ComplexityFunction in different cases.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch. The `ComplexityFunction` `Option` basically tells *Mathematica* that certain expressions are simpler than others. So by using this you can force *Mathematica* to see large expressions as simpler than smaller ones etc. Like you said just using `LeafCount` will work in certain cases but for more complex situations it fails to cause further simplification. The idea behind the `k Count...` part is to tell *Mathematica* that expressions with `Head` of `Log` or `ArcCoth` or `ArcCot` are expensive and should be further simplified if possible.

Comment: @RunnyKine. Have you been able to clarify why this does not work for 1/3 ? Thanks again.